# WSO2 API Manager Customisations in a Distributed (Clustered) Implementation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have implemented a small number of WSO2 API Manager (v1.10.0) customisations in our standalone (DEV environment) implementation.

However, now that I'm coming to implement this in the distributed UAT and PRD environments, I'm unsure of exactly which servers each of these customisations/configurations should go on.

We have the following distributed architecture:

- Gateway (x2)
- Publisher & Store (on a single server)
- Key Manager (x2)

This follows this design from [the online documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/API+Manager+Clustering+Deployment+Patterns#APIManagerClusteringDeploymentPatterns-Single):

[image: API Manager distributed architecture diagram]

The standard distributed install is all configured and working as expected.

The customisations that we've implemented are as follows:

### 1. Configure Custom Login Pages

By default, WSO2 uses its own logon page for the authentication of users. An example of this is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: WSO2 default login screen]

This is done by updating the contents of the `/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint' folder.

---

### 2. Configure to Skip User Consent

By default, the user is prompted to consent to the web application accessing their OpenID profile information:

[image]

This is done by changing the `<OpenIDConnect><SkipUserConsent>` value from `false` to `true` the Open the `\repostiory\conf\identity\identity.xml` file

---

### 3. Configuring User Account Recovery and Notifications

This is done by:

1. Installing the ‘Account Recovery and Credential Management’ feature in the WSO2 Admin interface
2. Setting the `IdentityMgtEventListener` to `true` in the `\repository\conf\carbon.xml` file
3. Updating the notification and useraccount settings in the `/repository\conf\identity\identity-mgt.properties` file
4. Uncommenting the `<transportSender name="mailto"...>` block in the `\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml` file

(Using the [Password Recovery](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Password+Recovery) instructions from the online documentation)

---

### 4. Configuring A Custom User Store Manager

Unfortunately, WSO2 currently does not support renaming users in the existing User Stores through the User Store Management APIs it exposes.

To enable our application to do this, we’ve implemented the Custom JDBC User Manager Store identified here: http://tharindue.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/a-workaround-for-renaming-username-of.html

---

### 5. Creating Claims

Here we have deleted the default `Username` claim and added two other claims (Rename Username & User ID) by following the instructions here: http://soasecurity.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/

---

Here's the question...

Which of the (distributed) servers or components should each of these customisations be done on?

My initial investigation suggests the following, but I wanted to confirm before starting to update configurations:

**1. Configure Custom Login Pages** - <s>Gateway servers</s> Key Manager servers

**2. Configure to Skip User Consent** - <s>Gateway servers</s> Key Manager servers

**3. Configuring User Account Recovery and Notifications** - Key Manager servers

**4. Configuring A Custom User Store Manager** - Key Manager servers

**5. Creating Claims** - Key Manager servers

Are these correct? Is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

Many thanks in advance! Jon

Comment: in `1`, which login are you talking about? Is that store, publisher or admin console of gateway manager? 
are you using identity server as keymanager?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bhathiya. This is not the login for any of the WSO2 API Manager components (store,publisher nor admin), it is the login page that my application users see when logging in to my site.

Comment: are you using identity server as keymanager?

Comment: No. We're using API Manager for the Key Manager.

Comment: Your 1st screenshot is of identity server. Do you have a separate IS?

Comment: Although the screenshot says "WSO2 Identity Server" in the heading, this was just the page that came embedded within the API Manager download (v1.10.0). Here's the full path to the JSP for this on my server: `C:\WSO2-APIM\repository\deployment\server\webapps\authenticationendpoint\login.jsp`. Here is the H1 element on that page: `<h1><em>Identity Server</em></h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to use API Manager as an Identity Provider. Even though API manager is capable of doing some of identity provider tasks as it has some features from Identity Server, you shouldn't use it as an identity server. Instead you should use a separate identity server, and do all your customizations for it.

You can also use the same identity servers as key manager nodes. IS as keymanager docs can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0). You simply have to install some API Manager features in Identity Server and do some configuration changes. Also there is a pre-packaged IS as Keymanager pack you can directly use. That's the recommended approach now. See docs [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.1.0+with+API+Manager+1.10.0).

Comment: Hi @Bhathiya. Thanks for your answer. I understand that using WSO2 Identity Server as the Key Manager may be a more appropriate approach. However, I followed the official [Clustering API Manager 1.10.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0) documentation, so I think that this should be possible using API Manager. If I can do these customisations on my standalone server, then surely I can do them on a distributed set up? Do you think that it is possible to do these customisations at all?

Comment: yes, customizations done in standalone can be moved to distributed setup as well.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. It's good to hear that the customisations can be moved too. What I was hoping to find out from my question is on which component (gateway, publisher, store or key manager) that each of the customisations need to be done on.

Comment: Since all identity management stuff should be in a single place, the best place would be key manager.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Sorry... Another question...Does that mean that I need to allow external users access to my Key Manager server (and move it to the DMZ) or will login requests still be routed through the Gateway?

Comment: No, you should not put key manager in DMZ as it needs to connect to userstore. You can do this instead. http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/10/06/deployment-pattern-of-wso2-identity-server-in-production/

Comment: Hi @Bhathiya. Apologies for the slight delay in replying - I've been on annual leave for a few days. That configuration makes sense now. We'll make sure to use a reverse proxy in the DMZ. Thanks for the link - it was really clear. I've accepted your answer and wish that I could give you more than one upvote! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help.